# Can A set with a finite Universe of discourse have an empty set?

Tags: logic

For example in a $\mathscr{U} = \{x\mid 1\le x \le 5\}$
can $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,\{1\},\{\}\}$?

Or can I only have numbers $[1,5]$ in the set like $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Sorry if this is a simple question.

Comment: Nope. It can only contain $1,\dots,5$. Otherwise building complements would be sensless.Or even simpler: by definition the universe must contain any of the considere sets, so $A$ cannot be of that form.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for the answer to this

Answer (score 1):

Your question title is **NOT** the same as your question body. **Yes** to your question title, but **no** to your question body.

If $U = \{\varnothing\}$, then $U$ contains the empty set, is finite, and can very well be a universe of discourse.

If $U = \{ x : x \in \mathbb{Z} \land 1 \le x \le 5 \}$, then $U = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and none of its members is the empty set!